# Request-URI Too Large :: IBM HTTP Server

Tags: url, uri, ibmhttpserver

We are using IBM HTTP Server Version 7.0

I am getting following error message on webpage

> **Request-URI Too Large**
>
> **The requested URL's length exceeds the capacity limit for this server**
>
> **IBM_HTTP_Server at WIN2K862 Port 80**

[LimitRequestLine](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/core.html#limitrequestline) is useful?

What changes I need to do to resolve this issue?

Answer (score 0):

LimitRequestLine clearly needs to be increased.